# Is it possible to use "kill" to send a signal to a process without forcing the process to exit?

Tags: linux, signals, kill

I have a shell script in which I can use "trap" command to capture the signals sent.

It will execute some function when specific signals are received.

I use the "kill" command to send the signal.

I just want to trigger the function in the script while not really kill the script.

Originally I thought the `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` should work, but I am wrong, the script just exited.

So is there a way to just use kill to send a signal to trigger some functions without really killing the process?

Comment: Show your shell script please.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Just an experimental script which will sleep forever and only print something whenever it receives the signal...I think as said by the following answer, I should not use "kill"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I got it. It exits only if my script just sleeps. If I add something between sleep, it works very well:>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man pages for kill and signal(7), the best you could hope for would be to stop and then maybe continue. But I don't think that will do what you want. I also question the desire to use "kill", a command whose name makes its intended purpose very clear, to do this. Almost every signal you can send with kill is intended to terminate a process or cause it to dump core. I'm not an expert but I think you are trying to use the wrong tool here.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe I should use other command to send the signal. Originally I thought "kill" is a generic way:>

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's rarely used, but I know of one common case you can reference.

dd

you can send a USR1 signal to dd while running and it will output progress.  Entirely userland and works great, fully portable code too.  Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)